# Google Maps Fusion Tables Query

Tags: javascript, sql, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to filter the data fusion tables return.

This is my code:

```
    // Set Fusion Table Layer
    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: 'geometry',
            from: fusionTable,
            where: whereQuery
        }
    });
```

whereQuery equals to this: name =' Antelope Valley | San Fernando | East Area | South Bay |name =' Antelope Valley | San Fernando | East Area | South Bay '

However, it is not firing correctly.

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the IN statement in your where clause, ie:

```
name IN ('Antelope Valley','San Fernando','East Area','South Bay')
```